# Hashrouter no slash with react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to add a hash with no slash to my path, like: `/#store/flowers/price` but since I'm not using **react-router-dom** **v5** anymore, the **v6** does not let me work with `<HashRouter hashType='noslash'>`

My code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { HashRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import FlowersPrice from './views/Store/Flowers/FlowersPrice'

return (
  <>
    <HashRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path={'/store/flowers/price'} element={<FlowersPrice />} />
      </Routes>
    </HashRouter>
  </>
 )
}  

export default App
```

This will only be available at `/#/store/flowers/price` and I want to still remove the slash `/#/store`

My react-router-dom version: **"react-router-dom": "^6.2.2"**

Comment: Looks like that behavior is non-existent in RRDv6. You might dig through the v5 source to see and understand how that prop was handled in the older version and try to create a custom router in v6 that applies the same/similar logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears this is no longer possible.

For those looking to just make their projects compatible with old URLs, you can force update any hash missing the leading "/". This is not the most elegant solution, but it solved it for me.

Add this to your index.js entry file:

```
const forceSlashAfterHash = () => {

    let _hash = window.location.hash;
    
    if (_hash[1] && _hash[1] != '/') {

        window.location.href = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + window.location.search + "#/" + _hash.slice(1);

    }

}

forceSlashAfterHash();

window.addEventListener('hashchange', forceSlashAfterHash);
```

When the page loads or the hash changes, it checks for a leading "/" in the hash, and if not present, adds one.