# Why is my component not rendering in react-router-dom v6 using hashrouter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Using react-router-dom v6.5.0

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <HashRouter history={history} >
    <Provider store={store}>
      <SnackbarProvider
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'bottom',
          horizontal: 'right',
        }}
      >
        <App />
      </SnackbarProvider>
    </Provider>
  </HashRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
const App = (props) => {
  return (
        <div>
            <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
              <Routes>
                <Route path='/*' element={<Splashpage userInfo={userInfo.toJS()} />}/>
                <Route path='cats' element={<Cats />} />
              </Routes >
        </div >
  );
};
```

My splashpage loads fine, although it has an extra "/" in the url. But when I go to "#cats" (using hashrouter) it says no routes matched. Changing the route path to "/cats" doesn't work either. However "/#/cats" renders Cats. How can I make it so Cats renders on "#cats"?

Comment: I don't think you can configure this. The RRDv6 version of the [`HashRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/hash-router) doesn't have a [`hashType`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter/hashtype-string) prop like v5 did. The route path RRDv6 used is everything after the hash, starting from the absolute path `"/"` as the "root" path the app is rendering on, a.k.a. `"...../#/`.

Comment: so if using hashrouter I have to render Cats at /#/cats?

Comment: No, `Cats`, as a component, is rendered on `"/cats"` and your app/router is rendered on `"url..../#"`. `"url...../#/cats"` is the URL path used to access that "page" of the app.

Comment: how come when my app is rendered it shows "url..../#/"? can i get rid of this last backslash?

Comment: The app is hosted/served from `"url..../#"` and the current app route is `"/"`, so the total path is `"url..../#"` + `"/"` or `"url..../#/"`.

Comment: I followed this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71398624/hashrouter-no-slash-with-react-router-dom-v6), and now I'm able to render all my components. however, is there any way to configure my URL so it doesn't look like "url..../#/component" and more like "url.../#component"??